# optimize sql query on website

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

So I have
a friends website and I'm trying to help him optimize the queries
because he got an email from the host, that his website was `eating` too
much resources. So looking at this query I was thinking, is there any way
this can be faster or smarter (consume less time or less memory) I don't
know which would be the best approach maybe prepared statements or some
improvement of the current code.

```
$query=@mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        tl.title, 
        tl.dt, 
        tk.nr as nr2, 
        tk.name as cat, 
        tf.name, 
        tf.type, 
        tf.alt,
        tt.trupi
    FROM 
        ".$tab['news']." as tl, 
        ".$tab['category']." as tk, 
        ".$tab['foto']." as tf, 
        ".$tab['entry']." as th, 
        ".$tab['body']." as tt
    WHERE 
        tl.nr = '$nr' AND 
        tl.foto = tf.nr AND 
        tl.kategoria = tk.nr AND 
        tl.hyrja = th.nr AND 
        tl.trupi = tt.nr");
```

I'd appreciate all of your suggestions,
Thank you.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing a description of the schema.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, you could use the ANSI 92 join syntax.

Combined with getting rid of two letter acronyms, that would have the benefit of making it clearer what your queries were doing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try...

```
$nr = mysql_real_escape_string( $nr );

$tab['category'] = mysql_real_escape_string( $tab['category'] );
$tab['foto']     = mysql_real_escape_string( $tab['foto'] );
$tab['entry']    = mysql_real_escape_string( $tab['entry'] );
$tab['body']     = mysql_real_escape_string( $tab['body'] );

$query = @mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        tl.title, 
        tl.dt, 
        tk.nr as nr2, 
        tk.name as cat, 
        tf.name, 
        tf.type, 
        tf.alt,
        tt.trupi
    FROM 
        ".$tab['news']." as tl
        LEFT JOIN ".$tab['category']." as tk ON ( tk.nr = tl.kategoria )
        LEFT JOIN ".$tab['foto']." as tf ON ( tf.nr = tl.foto )
        LEFT JOIN ".$tab['entry']." as th ON ( th.nr = tl.hyrja )
        LEFT JOIN ".$tab['body']." as tt ON ( tt.nr = tl.trupi )
    WHERE 
        tl.nr = '$nr'");
```

Note the escaping of variables before using them in an SQL string (See [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).)

Another thing to bear in mind is the design of the database in it's entirety. If there are any instances of "one-to-one" relationships between tables, then those two tables should be collapsed into a single table, etc.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use as for each and every table, and also use `Explain` to check how optimal your query is you can find a great guide here http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm on how to interpret the result of explain

All added actions to a query will decrease performance in one way or another, but I think the bottleneck is the join itself and the way you relate the tables. Try using integers(ids) when relating one table to another and if that's not possible make sure the column that your relating with is indexed. That would increase your query remarkable im certain.